Intersection of boundaries of closed sets
I can't seem to prove the following result... which seems obvious, and could not see a statement/proof online.

Consider $A$ and $B$, two closed and convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ and that $A\not\subseteq B$ and
$B\not\subseteq A$. Then, the intersection of their boundaries is not
empty, i.e. if $\partial A\neq \emptyset$ and $\partial
> B\neq\emptyset$, then $\partial A\cap \partial B\neq\emptyset$.

Convexity is probably not necessary. Of course, the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is closed and I can see that any $x\in \partial (A\cap  B)$ belongs either to $\partial A$ or $\partial B$, but I don't see how to show that there is always a point that belongs to both boundaries...
Any pointers?
Cheers

Convexity is necessary, or at least connectedness. There is a counterexample with non-connected sets. Set $A$ any ball of radius $R$, and $B$ the union of two balls, one insisde $A$ and one outside $A$.

Oh! Nice counterexample! Thanks, that definitely helps thinking about how to prove this.

Since this is all happening in $\Bbb{R}^n$, you could think of each point of the closure of $A \cap B$ labelled with the pair (distance from closure of $A$, distance from closure of $B$)...

I think I have a solution after intermediate result $\exists x_0 \in A \cap B \land x_0 \in \partial A$ is proven. This is direct result of $A$ being connected and neither $A$ or $B$ is a proper subset of another.

$A = [0,2], B = [1, 3]$ is a counter-example when $n = 1$. For higher $n$, you can just cross it with $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.
The key here is of course that the boundaries of $A$ and $B$ are not connected.
Edit: $A = (-\infty, 1], B = [0, \infty)$ provides a counter-example with connected boundaries.

Isn't this a counter-example for the theorem, as stated? Both $A$ and $B$ are closed and convex.

@JohnDouma - Yes. That is why I called it a counter-example. The "theorem" as stated is false.

The discussion in the comments seems to suggest that convexity is needed to prove the theorem, not that the theorem is false even if we have convex sets. That's why I pointed it out. This answer should be accepted.

Ohhh, right! Thanks
